# Where is os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data') in Linux/Windows?

Tags: python

Where is the folder the following code is creating on different operating systems?

```
data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    import generate_data
    os.mkdir(data_dir)
```

Is it `/path/to/file/data`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.path.dirname` gives you the directory its argument is in, and `os.path.join` appends a file or directory to the given directory.

`os.path` provides you with a platform-independent way to modify file and directory paths, making use of the appropriate types of slashes.

So yes, this will create a 'data' directory (if it doesn't already exist) within the same directory as the source file from which this code is run.

Answer (score 7):

`__file__` is the full path to where the file that contains the code is running; so its going to be the directory from which the file that contains the snippet was executed.